# How to do full-line search with Tabulator?

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, tabulator

Needing for "global search" filter interface for [modern Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/), something like UNIX `grep` command, or default *search* of [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) ([ref1](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searching),[ref2](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search())).

This [*Tabulator issue* was closed](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/505) with no solution, and [**filter** Guide](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/filter) say nothing about full-search (perhaps multiple filter with **all columns** and boolean OR).

Comment: See also [GIT/tabulator/issues/505](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/505#issuecomment-754660925)

Answer (score 2):

The issue you reference includes the correct answer in the first reply, which is why it is closed.

It creates a custom filter function that looks for the value passed into the ***value*** property on params object.

The function is then called using the ***setData*** function

```js
//custom filter function
function matchAny(data, filterParams){
    //data - the data for the row being filtered
    //filterParams - params object passed to the filter

    var match = false;

    for(var key in data){
        if(data[key] == filterParams.value){
            match = true;
        }
    }

    return match;
}

//set filter to custom function
table.setFilter(matchAny, {value:5});
```

Comment: does exactly what you described! works like a charm. thanks!